# AWS Cloud formation for Cloud Trail put event selector

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

In short, I want to enable cloud trail for several objects in different S3 buckets. I am able to directly mention all the objects when creating CloudTrail from CloudFormation. But i want to add them at later point in time.

- Create an AWS CloudTrail trail in a CloudFormation stack and export the trail's ARN.
- Then when creating objects in S3 bucket to which i need CloudTrail data events for, I want to add them as this existing CloudTrail.

Here is the spot in console where I can manually add it.
[CloudTrail AWS Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLTod.png)

So, Looking to add data events to an existing CloudTrail via CloudFormation.

Looked entire documentation several times, I can only see a way to add while creating the CloudTrail: 
[Create a CloudWatch Events Rule for an Amazon S3 Source (AWS CloudFormation Template) - CodePipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/create-cloudtrail-S3-source-cfn.html)

Please advice what is the resource type that supports this?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your second bullet-point. Can you explain it in more detail, perhaps referring to how you would do this in the management console?

Comment: I am sorry , its not very clear. I just edited and added a screen shot, hope this helps.

Comment: What are you wanting to capture in CloudTrail for these objects? If you want to capture information about when the objects are accessed, you can use [Amazon S3 Server Access Logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html).

Comment: I am triggering code pipeline based on these events. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/create-cloudtrail-S3-source.html

Answer (score 0):

you can probably get some hint from the CFT I have created - from an S3 Event probably an putObject operations logs the events details into an separate bucket from where using CloudWatch Events trigger the execution of the Step Function State Machine.

```
cloudtrail:
    Type: AWS::CloudTrail::Trail
    Properties:       
      EnableLogFileValidation: Yes
      EventSelectors: 
        - DataResources:
            - Type: AWS::S3::Object
              Values: 
                - arn:aws:s3:::s3-event-step-bucket/    
          IncludeManagementEvents: Yes
          ReadWriteType: All
      IncludeGlobalServiceEvents: Yes
      IsLogging: Yes
      IsMultiRegionTrail: Yes
      S3BucketName: s3-event-step-bucket-storage       
      TrailName: xyz
```

When you deploy this CFT , it will update the existing Trail with CloudTrail data events as the Trigger Point.

Comment: doesn't this just attempt to create a new trail ?

Comment: it will create a new trail and if the trail already exists it will update the existing trail also, probably the IAM should have the update permissions, please also note that the trigger event is set to All types which will cover all the Events.## If the Trail is created through Console at the First Time, I am yet to try updating it with CFT.

Comment: This will only work if the Trail was first created in this stack. You can't create a Trail in one stack and then add the above extract to another stack as you will get an error: "Resource of type 'AWS::CloudTrail::Trail' with identifier 'codepipeline-source-trail' already exists.". This means you cannot update a Trail that was created in the console.